# Text entry in UITableview similar to "Tasks/Reminders" app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

Goal: To create a text entry method similar to the iOS **Tasks/Reminders/Schedule** app

I know how to add a `UITextView` to a *dynamic* `UITablviewCell` and make it editable, switch off scrolling and make the cell to dynamically adjust its height according to the text been entered.

I also use the method `textViewShouldEndEditing` to figure out where the *cursor* is.

Where I'm struggling and need you guys/girls help is in figuring out how to keep dynamically adding cells when the user hits enter on the keyboard so they can start typing in the next cell below.
Also, when loading the app, I'm currently setting the `numberOfRowsInSection` to 10, is there a way I don't hard code the value?

I would also like to add the plus button to the next cell to be added just like in the iOS app, if you can direct me in the right way, that would be terribly great.

Thank you all in advance
[image: recording of what I'm trying to achive]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !isIngredients{
        return Method.count
    } else {
        return listItems.count
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddMetaDetails", for: indexPath) as! tvcAddMetaDetails

    if isIngredients {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(listItems[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    } else  {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(Method[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if !islistItems {
        Method.append(txtAddMetaDetails.text!)
        txtAddMetaDetails.text = ""
        tvAddMetaDetails.reloadData()
    } else {
        listItems.append(txtAddMetaDetails.text!)
        txtAddMetaDetails.text = ""
        tvAddMetaDetails.reloadData()
    }
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    tvAddMetaDetails.estimatedRowHeight = 60
    tvAddMetaDetails.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
     return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: kindly add your try code.

Comment: @SGDev do you have any suggestions as to how I can achieve this? The has been added

Answer (score 1):

[image]So, I didn't quite achieve what I wanted but got close enough. I will do more customisations and add to the response, but for those who would like a head start, here is the solution:

1. added a uitable to a ui view controller
2. assigned the table delegate and data source to the controller
3. added two dynamic cells
4. gave them names such as EntryCell and DisplayCell
5. added a textView to the 2nd cell, gave constraints to margin and set to NOT scroll but editable.
6. made the view controller the delegate for the textView
7. Made an outlet for the table to the viewcontroller and an outlet for the textview to the TableViewCell class file, which you need to create

now what I also wanted was, when the user hits the enter key, I wanted the data to be saved and the cursor to move to the next cell. for this, I did the changes in shouldChangeTextIn

Code is pasted, a screenshot of the storyboard is also added, I'm sure the instructions are not too clear and to code is not well commented, but feel free to ask questions and I will do my best to help you. I know the struggle when things are new and I'm not a developer by profession :(

```js
import UIKit

class test2VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var metaTable: UITableView!
    
    var metaArray = [String]()
   
    //var textView: test2TVC.txtEntry
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        metaTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        metaTable.separatorInset = .zero //MakeTable Separator go to the edge
        metaTable.layoutMargins = .zero
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //metaArray.append("Test String")
        
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
   
    
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            
            metaArray.append(textView.text)
            //textView.text = ""
            
            metaTable.reloadData()
            scrollToBottom()
            
            //dump(metaArray)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    //hide and show keyboard and move table
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
        
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            metaTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
        }
    }
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification:Notification) {
        
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            metaTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        metaTable.beginUpdates()
        metaTable.endUpdates()
    }
    
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
        if (textView.text == "Type something here..." && textView.textColor == .lightGray)
        {
            textView.text = ""
            textView.textColor = .black
        }
        textView.becomeFirstResponder() //Optional
    }
    
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
        if (textView.text == "")
        {
            textView.text = "Type something here..."
            textView.textColor = .lightGray
        }
        //textView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    func scrollToBottom(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
            self.metaTable.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    
    /*func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if (text as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.newlines).location == NSNotFound {
            return true
        }
        txtView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }*/
    
   
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (section == 0) {
            return metaArray.count
        } else if (section == 1){
            return 1
        }
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cellIdentifier = ""
        switch (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section {
        case 0:
            cellIdentifier = "DisplayCell"
        case 1:
            cellIdentifier = "EntryCell"
        default: ()
        }
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! test2TVC
        
        if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = metaArray[indexPath.row]
        } else if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 1) {
            //cell.txtEntry?.text = "Test"
           
            cell.txtEntry.text = "Type something here..."
            cell.txtEntry.textColor = .lightGray
            
            
        }
      
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView //recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        //header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 204/255, green: 229/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0) //make the background color light blue
        header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0) //make the background color white
        //header.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9738872647, green: 0.9682117105, blue: 0.9014379382, alpha: 1)
        //header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.lightGray //make the text lightGray
        header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.black //make the text Black
        header.textLabel!.textAlignment = .left //Align text Center
        header.textLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25) //Header text font size
        header.alpha = 0.95 //make the header transparent
        header.alpha = 1 //make the header non-transparent
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if (section == 0) {
            return 62
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if (section == 0){
            return " Ingredients"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
```